# How to set dropdown width to match dropdown content width in antd?

Tags: css, antd

The option `dropdownMatchSelectWidth` is [deprecated](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/issues/21908#issuecomment-595204918). How could you do it now, given that each `<Select.Option>` item might have a slightly different content width. So it's like you would have to iterate through the select options, get their width, find the max, then set the `dropdownStyle` to be the max child element width?

It is fine the the select *input* is an explicit width, but ideally the *dropdown content* is dynamic width (up to some max, so it doesn't go outside the screen perhaps?).

Answer (score 1):

You can build custom js function to handle this. Like that:

```js
const o = document.querySelectorAll('option')
const lenMax = 15
o.forEach(e => {
  if (e.textContent.length > lenMax) {
    e.textContent = e.textContent.substring(0,lenMax) + '...';  
  }
  
})
```

```css
select {
  width: 250px;
}

option {
  width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<select>
  <option>lorem ipsum</option>
  <option>lorem ipsumlorem ipsum lorem ipsum</option>
  <option>lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Yeah, if this is the only thing :) I will do it. But it is a last resort.

Comment: @Alien Yeah, Last resort https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=j0lSpNtjPM8